# Delete parts of a linear array

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I think this question has not been answered. Suppose I generate a random linear array with only two entries -1 or +1. From this array I want to delete all sequences that alternate such as {-1,1,-1,1,-1,1} or {1,-1,1,-1,1,-1} and similar *longer* sub-sequences but not shorter ones (which I want to retain) e.g. I want to retain sub-sequences such as {-1,1,-1,1} and {1,-1} etc. I know how to delete a particular sub-sequence but I don't know how to delete all sub-sequences that are longer than 4 alternating signs.

```
f[k_] := 2 RandomInteger[] - 1

RanList[m_] := Array[f, m]

DeleteCases[RanList[100], {-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1}] (* for example *)
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `SequenceReplace[]`: `SequenceReplace[RanList[100], {-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1} -> Nothing]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123]
rl = RanList[100]
```

> ```
>  {-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
>    -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
>    -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 
>    1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 
>    1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
> ```

```
SequenceReplace[pat : {Repeated[PatternSequence[-1, 1], {4, Infinity}] | 
      Repeated[PatternSequence[1, -1], {4, Infinity}]} :> 
   Sequence @@ ( Style[#, Red] & /@ pat)]@rl
```

> [image]

```
SequenceReplace[{Repeated[PatternSequence[-1, 1], {4, Infinity}] | 
     Repeated[PatternSequence[1, -1], {4, Infinity}]} -> Nothing]@rl
```

> ```
>   {-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1,
>     -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 
>     -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 
>      1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 
>      -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
> ```